# Searching for key words in a large file (Java/Scala)

Tags: java, scala

I have a large File ~120MB which contains UTF 8 encoded Strings and I need to search for certain words in this file.

The format of the file looks like this:
`[resource]<label>[resource]<label>[resource]<label>...` including braces as one huge line so I can read it fast into memory.
I search only in the labels and return the labels and resources where a label contains one or more of the key words. Both the labels and the key words are in lower case.

Currently I load the whole file and create a list of Strings. Each entry in this list contains a pair of resource and label in the format `[resource]<label>`. And the size of this list is approximately 3,000,000. I "iterate" through this list with a tail recursive function and look if my labels contains one of the key words. This is quite fast (<800ms) but this search needs a lot of Memory and CPU-Power

My searchfunction looks like this

```
    @tailrec
    def search2( l: List[String], list: List[(String, String)]): List[(String, String)] = {
        l match {
            case Nil => list
            case a :: as => {
                val found = keyWords.foldRight(List.empty[(String, String)]) { (x, y) =>
                    if (a.contains(x)) {
                        val split = a.split("<")
                        if (split.size == 2) { (split(0).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""), split(1)) :: y }
                        else { y }
                    } else { y }
                }
                search2(as, found ::: list)
            }
        }

    }
    search2(buffer, Nil) //buffer is the list with my 3,000,000 elements
```

The search needs to be really fast (< 2 seconds). I already tried the MappedByteBuffer but the UTF 8 encoding made it quite difficult to search for a byte sequence and it was really slow (but maybe my search function was just bad).

If needed I could change the format or even split labels and resources into two different files.

Comment: You state you are at 800ms which is less then 2s, so what is the question here?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to reparse the file every time you search for an element.

Read your file once for all and put the words in a `Map[String, Set[String]]`.

Something like:

```
val allWords: Map[String, Seq[String]] = 
  Source.fromFile(file)
        .getLines()
        .head
        .split(extractLabelResources)
        .groupBy { case (label, resource) => label }
        .mapValues(_.toSeq)

def extractLabelResources(line: String): Array[(String, String)] = {
    // ...
}

def search(word: String): Set[String] = allWords.getOrElse(word, Set.empty)
```